# Android Studio "Start Failed" on Windows 8 64bit

Tags: android

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74801

This is the issue I logged with google and have yet to hear back. But I am wondering if there would be anyone on here that has gotten similar issues with Android Studio and have resolved them?

Basically I added ArgoUML plugin to Studio and had to restart on when it restarted I got a nice big error saying it failed to start with a massive list of stuff ( attached pic on the google issue has this image of the error). 
I am using studio for a college project and am still a noob when it comes to programming so most of what it says in the error message is gobbledygook! 
I did several re-install of Studio but still got the same message but I can see even after a the re-installs that near the end ArgoUML is mentioned?! Any idea's why this is happening?

Cheers,
Owen

Comment: have your tried removing the plugin?

Comment: I don't see it in the files within the plugin folder in Studio to remove. Since i did reinstall it a few times i didn't think it would be there anymore. Is is in it's own folder like ArgoUML etc or within another?

Comment: or could it be that it's in the .AndroidStudioBeta folder within the user folders? I never checked that?!

Comment: aaaand that worked...cheers Mr BadWolf twas the remnants of the old files in there :)

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I think I found out why the plugin crashed.

The plugin tries to load a "sync.png" icon ([code here](http://sourceforge.net/p/argoidea/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/org/argoidea/images/Icons.java#l32)) from the IDE, but there is no sync icon in recent releases. This causes an uncaught NullPointerException, which you can see on the very last line of the error message.

Comment: good to know. I shall use Visual Paradigm SDE mentioned in another topic. cheers for that sir!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @jaket, thanks for the tips. will know for next time :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was posted by [Bad Wolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1028089/badwolf) above in the comments, was to delete the plugin from the .AndroidStudioBeta folder within the user folders (of windows), this resolved the issue.

Even after re-installing Android Studio the files remained in the user folders so just to be aware if anyone else is having an issue with faulty plugins.